# PhoneGap или Cordova?

Tags: phonegap, android, cordova

День добрый! Объясните, пожалуйста, есть ли различия между PhoneGap и Cordova?

Просто хотел сделать мобильную версию приложения, и не могу понять, в чем их различия.

В Сети говорят, что они одинаковые фреймворки, то phonegap  лучше, некоторые за cordova-у.
У  меня нету опыта в этих технологиях, вот и спрашиваю, что выбрать.

Netbeans как бы рекомендует из коробки cordovu https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted_ru.html, плагина для phonegap не смог найти.

И еще вопрос: с помощью каких из них (phonegap, cordova) можно получить доступ к дисплею (включать/выключить) смартфона (андроид)? Спасибо.

Comment: вы хоть бы утрудились прочитать на [википедии][1], что ли первое предложение...    

> PhoneGap (называемый также Apache Callback, **основанный на Apache Cordova**) 


  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cordova - фреймворк с открытым кодом. Phonegap - обертка для этого фреймворка, принадлежащая Adobe и позволяющая теснее взаимодействовать с другими сервисами Adobe. В первую очередь, с Phonegap Build - это облачный сервис на основе Phonegap, который на основе Cordova, *в доме, который построил Джек.* О нем ниже.

С практической точки зрения, разницы между Phonegap и Cordova нет. Оба устанавливаются локально, оба умеют подтягивать плагины из репозиторев, оба имеют одни и те же глюки, т.к. код в основе один. Разница выглядит примерно так:

```
$usr> phonegap local build android //local - потому что не в облаке, можно remote

$usr> cordova build android //кордова всегда локальна
```

Я выбрал Cordova, т.к.:

1. Интеграция с облаком мне не нужна. Я всегда выбираю более "тонкий" стек технологий.
2. Phonegap апдейтится почти одновременно с Cordova, но не одновременно. Например, поддержка 64-bit iOS apps там припозднилась на месяц.
3. Я за open source и не люблю Adobe.

Как-то раз мне пришлось переключиться с Cordova на Phonegap Build (я делал и тестировал приложение локально, заказчик создавал бинарники в облаке со своими ключами). Переход занял примерно день, в основном на отлов мелких багов, когда что-то в Cordova работало, а в Phonegap Build - нет.

Например, длительность сплэш-заставки в Cordova прописывается в config.xml:

```
<preference SplashScreenDelay="3000"/>
```

Phonegap Build эту настройку проигнорировал, поэтому пришлось подключать плагин для управления заставкой через JavaScript и делать это руками.

Comment: + Cordova поддерживается как минимум Visual Studio 2013 и выше

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно